# Retrieve a single value from WinForms groupBox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, groupbox

I am new to Visual Studio and C#.  I am creating a WinForms app that calculates a monthly mortgage payment which requires a Text Box (for principle), a Combo Box (for interest rate),a Group Box which requires 2 Radio Buttons (15 and 30 years) and and "other" button that opens up a Text Box for user-entered years, and a Button that performs the calculation when clicked.  Is there a way to reference just one single value in the group box when I do my calculation, or do I need to do an If statement for each Radio Button and Text Box and put that in my button_Click method?  Preferably, I would like the button_Click method to simply call a separate method which performs the calculation and place it in an output string. This is the code I have thus far:

```
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double yrs;
        bool success;
        if (rdo15.Checked)
            success = double.TryParse(rdo15.Text, out yrs);
        else if (rdo30.Checked)
            success = double.TryParse(rdo30.Text, out yrs);
        else
            success = double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out yrs);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msgStr = string.Format("Your monthly payment will be {0}", payment());
        MessageBox.Show(msgStr);
    }

    private double payment()
    {
        double intRate = Double.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
        double prin = Double.Parse(txtPrin.Text);
        double yrs = Double.Parse(groupBox1.Text);
        //payment calculation
    }
```

I realize I need to convert to money format, etc, after the calculation.  I am able to retrieve all values with the last method (payment) except those from the group box.  I know there must be an easy way to just grab one of those values (from either radio button or the textBox) and just plug it into my math equation.  Any tips on how to approach it?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should use decimal for money if it's for a real application. You could alway use a switch case but if you only have 2 radiobutton it's ok to do it via if else if

Answer (score 1):

you should continue to use your if/else if/else combination but you can change a couple things.

make a class level variable that will store the value as such.

`double years = [enter default value if you wish]`

You can then use this throughout your class.

In your chosen method, you can then set this variable as you are doing (below is slightly more efficient as not needing to set unused variables).

```
if (rdo15.Checked)
   years = 15;
else if (rdo30.Checked)
   years = 30;
else
   double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out years);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I realize I could do a class variable to reference in the calculation but I would prefer to keep it private.  I am more interested in a way to call whatever value is selected within the group box in my calculation method (payment).  double yrs = Double.Parse(groupBox1.Text) is not retrieving a value but I would imagine there is another way to get that.

Comment: how do you mean keep it private? it would still be private to the class, its only public if labelled as such

Comment: Sorry, I meant I wanted it to be local to that method only.  I ended up tossing that idea and calling the groupBox values from the Button_Clicked (which I didn't want to do) because I couldn't figure out how to call one value from the groupBox as a method.  I guess you can't do that.  At least couldn't find any documentation.  Thanks to all who responded though.

Comment: I wouldnt necessarily say you are keeping it private as you are using its value in another method, but getting it twice

Answer (score 0):

You really will be best served by an if statement:

```
if (rad15years.checked)
    years = 15;
else if (rad30years.checked)
    years = 30;
else 
    years = int.Parse(txtCustomYears.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be an overkill for your needs, but I suggest using a `ListBox` instead of multiple radio buttons. You could then have a dictionary `DataSource` where key is your period in years, and value is this period in human readable terms. So you will have two `(Key,Value)` pairs there for now:

```
{15, "15 Years"}
{30, "30 Years"}
```

And you could do `ListBox1.SelectedValue`, which returns 15 and 30 respectively, of correct data type, should be able to plug into your formula directly from there. The benefit this approach also gives you is that you can extend this easily, and start supporting periods of `25 years` etc.

If for any reason, you would like to continue using radio buttons, I suggest you create a custom class, which would hold its `Years` value in a custom property. So you configure one to `15` in forms designer, and another one to `30`. Then it's as simple as looping through all of them, and, if checked, grab its `Years` property and inject into your formula for further processing. This is also extensible to support any number of radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm sure that would work but the specs for the project require me to use 3 radio buttons.  2 with fixed values and one that provides access to a text box.